# How can I find the aplication layer protocol that is being used and shown in the Wireshark window

Tags: networking, wireshark, network-protocols

Hi everyone I'm trying to find the name of the application layer protocol that belongs to the frame 7 shown below. I'm trying to find it just by looking at the metric values and the routing info, that's why I have blurred the name in the image.
[Fig.1: Traffic screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4A34.png)

Thanks guys! I'm just curious, and I'm pretty sure that there's a way to find the protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's to and from a well-known port (520/UDP), so you look it up in `/etc/services` or in IANA's list of well-known ports, and you discover that it's RIP. In general, if a protocol uses UDP or TCP and one of the ports is a well-known port (i.e. below 1024), then it's probably the well known protocol that the port is known for.